# Android : How to show multiple webrtc videotracks in custom view, like video view, or horizontal scrollview or recyclerview?

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, android-videoview, pubnub

I am building an android application which has group video calling feature. 
I want to show multiple user's remote video stream in horizontal scrollview. Webrtc's VideoRendererGui has static instance also I don't want to draw remote streams.

I also want to make remote stream view selectable. For all these things I am using PubNub.

Comment: The video streaming will not be sent over PubNub. PubNub is used strictly for the signal protocol. See [this KB article for full details](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-provide-webrtc-and-video-chat).

Comment: Do you solve it? if yes, can you post your solution here? will be very appreciate!